# click event triggered automatically in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Can anyone explain to me why the on click event is being triggered without any clicking actually happening?

```
     var svgWindow = d3.select("body")
                          .append("svg")
                          .attr("width", widthWindow)
                          .attr("height", heightWindow)
                          .attr("x", svgXWindow)
                          .attr("y", svgYWindow);

      var windowContainer=svgWindow.append("g").attr("id", "window_container");


      var userNodes=windowContainer.append("g")
                                    .attr("class", "userNode") 
                                    .attr("id","useriddata")
                                    .selectAll(".userNode")
                                    .on("click", alert('error'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be in a `function(){}` so that the alert will only be executed when the `click` event is fired:

```
var userNodes=windowContainer.append("g")
                             .attr("class", "userNode") 
                             .attr("id","useriddata")
                             .selectAll(".userNode")
                             .on("click", function(){alert('error');});
```

Otherwise `alert()` is evaluated, ( and so called ), once the `userNodes` is called, and so it fires the `alert()` without even being clicked. Once its in a function, the function is evaluated once `userNodes` is called ad then its only executed on click.

Comment: Yes, I realized it and solved the problem, and came back to answer my own question but found that you had already answered it. Thanks anyways!